# PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] based form not working with additional variables

Tags: php, forms

I have taken reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082429/php-echo-serverphp-self-with-added-variable) But unfortunately, the solution is not working in my case with the registration form.

My user registration works in two steps.

STEP 1: 
1st we get user email, then verify it by sending them registration link. On the link we include affiliate code, email & email in hashed form, email sending time etc
This part works flawlessly.

STEP 2:
Upon on the registration link page with those all additional `variables` the full form loads. First with all get variable.
We check that registration link is valid or not, expiry matter etc with following code snippet.

```
if(isset($_GET['key'],$_GET['reset'],$_GET['keyid'],$_GET['af']))
```

Then when everything is all right we move to the main registration form, otherwise, form doesn't loads for invalid link.

With LasVegasCoder coding this is the registration link:(Not much different than my original)

> http://localhost/clientphp/register.php?key=tester@gmail.com&reset=2fbb7857ace656c855dd9ed9cdc79631998231fe73251df09063f307c21084c65905ca4172b7e7cf4108bbbca41c7f4b51690498fb622a8a54a5e5cad3d25572&keyid=1504104584&af=1

**Here is the form code:**

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="registration_form" 
      action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?
      key="'.$email."&reset=".$email_hash."&keyid=".$email_time."&af=".$af_code)?>">
      Somecode
</form>
```

With current form coding, it shows error.

> Error 403. Access forbidden.

The form contains, *Username, Pin, Country, Password & confirm Password* fields. I check its parameters from server side if user failed to input correct details then it shows up error on the same page. Otherwise registration successful moved to other page.

**Update:**
The whole process involves 2 files.

- register.php
- register.inc.php (This is the file which checks
  everything from server side if all pass then redirects to
  register-success.php page)

If the user gives any wrong input it gets shown up on the register.php page where he is filling the form.

```
    if (!empty($error_msg)) {
       echo $error_msg;
    }
```

This $error_msg comes from register.inc.php files. Hope it clears everything now.

Comment: You write "*the form doesn't work*" but you don't give specifics about what happens and how it's different from what you expect to happen.

Comment: Please check the last line where I mentioned it shows Error 403 Access forbidden. Updating the question with more example about how I expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have GET arguments passed in URL and method POST for your form. But ya need to choose one method, **you cannot use both GET and POST** in the same time. So, the best is to use hidden input with all the GET values passed in POST.

And you can ommit action argument, that will post form on the same page.

For example :

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="registration_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="reset" value="<?php echo $email_hash;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="keyid" value="<?php echo $email_time;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="af" value="<?php echo $af_code;?>">
    Somecode
</form>
```

Comment: If user inputs wrong, then it url changed to this `http://localhost/clientphp/register.php?key=` not working.

Comment: Yes, while your arguments (GET) are ignored by the server... because you use POST method.

Comment: This is a good idea, actually, I don't need to save $email_hash, $email_time I just use those variable tempurarliy to check if the registration link is valid or not or didn't got expired. So use this before everything  `if(isset($_GET['key'],$_GET['reset'],$_GET['keyid']))`

Comment: And store email then use hidden input already `<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">`

Comment: Tested doesn't work neither shows error alerts if user inputs wrong.

Comment: Well, interesting... Let's chat about it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153259/room-for-meloman-and-mimi

Answer (score 1):

#### Using PHP_SELF is a bad idea!

*But if insist to use it in development, you may concatenate your link and append it as query parameters as follows:*

```
 $link  = "$email";
 $link .= "&reset=$email_hash";
 $link .= "&keyid=$email_time";
 $link .= "&af=$af_code";

 <form method="get" class="form-horizontal" name="registration_form" 
  action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?key=$link; ?>">
    Somecode
 </form>
```

#### Preferred Method:

```
 $link  = "$email";
 $link .= "&reset=$email_hash";
 $link .= "&keyid=$email_time";
 $link .= "&af=$af_code";

 <form method="get" class="form-horizontal" name="registration_form" 
  action="process.php?key=$link" >

    other codes goes here
 </form>
```

#### Based on our discussion, find below email verification sending codes;

```
 $link  = "$email";
 $link .= "&reset=$email_hash";
 $link .= "&keyid=$email_time";
 $link .= "&af=$af_code";


    $activation = "http://your-domain.com/activate.php?key=$link";

    // send email to our new client;
    $mailTo   = $email;
    $mailFrom   = "noreply@your-domain.com";
    $subject    = "Welcome to My Affiliate Service";
    $headers    = "From: $mailFrom";
    $mailBody   = "Please activate your account to start banking revenue! 
                    <a href=' . $activation . '>ACTIVAT NOW</a>";

    if( @mail( $mailTo, $subject, $mailBody, $headers ) )
    {
        //mail sent
        // do something
    }
    else{
        // mail not sent..
        // check why.
    }
```

**Good luck**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153270/discussion-between-lasvegascoder-and-mimi).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay on the same page, you dont have to input that. Just start with `?` and you'll submit to the current page, with those parameters:

```
$formAction = '?key="'.$email.'&reset='.$email_hash.'&keyid='.$email_time.'&af='.$af_code;

<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="registration_form" 
      action="<?=formAction?>">
      <!-- FORM HERE -->
</form>
```

Using PHP_SELF is a bad idea anyways.

Comment: I applied your code, still, shows 404 error if the user makes any wrong input. doesn't returns back on the same page.

Comment: still same error 403 sorry previously mistyped as 404

Comment: 403 is a permission denied. I dont know what you're doing, but you should check the url when you get the error, figure out what it should be and conclude what part you're missing